# what is synchronization - a property?

Tags: concurrency, synchronization, deadlock, race-condition

I am having a general doubt regarding synchronization ->

When we say mutual exclusion is satisfied between 2 processes, i mean it is property which is desirable. It is not a problem to be solved.

Similarly, deadlock, race condition are problems to be solved

**So, synchronization is also a property which should be maintained, that is, "Is it something desirable" or "a problem which needs to be solved" ?**

Answer (score 1):

The desireable properties are

- thread-safety, or preserving the integrity of some data structure from changes made concurrently that could corrupt the contents of that data structure, and
- liveness, which is the ability of your threads to make progress.

Synchronization is a means to the end of preserving the integrity of shared data without impeding liveness. It is only one of a number of techniques which aim at preserving thread safety.

Synchronization can become a problem if you have a deadlock, or if a bottleneck develops (if too many threads need to acquire the same lock and most of them can't make progress), so that the program may be thread-safe but liveness becomes an issue.